# Prohibit looping functions

Tags: javascript

Function onSuccess runs indefinitely, as constantly asks the coordinates from the GPS receiver. It contains a function createMap, to be performed only once. How is this achieved? Make a function outside the function also can not, because it is passed as a parameter value of a variable of the function.

```
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {onSuccess(position, arrMyLatLng);}, onError, options);  

function onSuccess(position, arrMyLatLng) 
{

var latitude , longitude ;     
latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
longitude = position.coords.longitude;
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

createMap(myLatLng, arrMyLatLng);// This feature will run for an indefinite number of times. It is only necessary once. 
map.panTo(myLatLng) ;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `createMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function with private state using a closure:

```
onSuccess = (function() {
    var created = false;
    return function (position, arrMyLatLng) {
        var latitude , longitude ;     
        latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        if (!created) {
            createMap(myLatLng, arrMyLatLng);
            created = true;
        }
        map.panTo(myLatLng) ;
    };
}());
```

Comment: onSuccess constainly update, and "created" will be false always

Comment: No, the first time onSuccess runs, `created` will be false and thus the if control structure runs, creating your map and setting `created` to true. From there on, each next call to onSuccess, `created` will be true.

Comment: @user2244523 - No, that's not how it will work. `created` will be set to `false` when `onSuccess` is first assigned. Note that `onSuccess` is the (anonymous) function returned by the outer function. The first time `onSuccess` runs, `created` will be set to `true` and there's no way for it to be set to `false` again.

Comment: ok. how it fix in line watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {onSuccess(position, arrMyLatLng);}, onError, options);

Comment: @user2244523 - Why does that line need fixing? It should all work as you want. The first time the success call-back function is called, it will set the private `created` variable to `true` and from then on the call-back will skip the call to `createMap`. Just try it!

Comment: thank you.  but i still don't understand why var created = false; run just 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

Function that runs only once:

```
function runOnce() {
    if (runOnce.done) {
         return;
    } else {
       // do my code ...

       runOnce.done = true;
    }
}
```

Because function is object in JavaScript, you may set a property on it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `createMap` returns a map

```
var map = null;

function onSuccess(position, arrMyLatLng) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    map = map || createMap(myLatLng, arrMyLatLng);
    map.panTo(myLatLng);
}
```

`createMap` will only run if `map` evaluates to "false" (i.e. is `null`), thus createMap only runs once.